# Can I trust in memory information of dmicode?

Tags: linux, memory, x86

I want to buy 16gb memory for my notebook.
I ran `dmicode` and found this information:

```
Handle 0x0005, DMI type 5, 20 bytes
Memory Controller Information
        Error Detecting Method: None
        Error Correcting Capabilities:
                None
        Supported Interleave: One-way Interleave
        Current Interleave: One-way Interleave
        Maximum Memory Module Size: 8192 MB
        Maximum Total Memory Size: 16384 MB
        Supported Speeds:
                Other
        Supported Memory Types:
                Other
        Memory Module Voltage: Unknown
        Associated Memory Slots: 2
                0x0006
                0x0007
        Enabled Error Correcting Capabilities:
                None
```

My point:
`Maximum Total Memory Size: 16384 MB`

Can I trust that information and buy 16gb of memory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could - probably. From the `man` page:

> While this is a good point in terms  of report  speed  and  safeness,
>   this also makes the presented information possibly unreliable.

You'll also still need to work out exactly what type and what speed that you'll need for your laptop.

Why not use http://www.crucial.com or a similar site and enter the details of your laptop in there.  It'll tell you all you need to know.